# In ROR, how can I close an open database connection if any error occurs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception

My rails controllers often open an ODBC connection with an external database (ruby-ODBC), and call many methods with that open connection as a parameter, and then close that connection just before rendering.
eg

```
def show
    dbh=ODBC.connect(dsn_name,username,password)
    @author = getAuthor(dbh,params[:id])
    @books= getBooks(dbh,@author)
    dbh.disconnect
end
```

If an error occurs in any of the methods in the controller, the connection (dbh) is not closed. This leads to too many open connections.

I have added a generic 'rescue_from' in my application controller to check to see if a database connection is open when an error occurs, but the block does not have access to any variables from the method where the error occurred, including dbh.

```
    in application_controller.rb
    
      rescue_from StandardError, :with => :close_db_connection
    
      def close_db_connection
        if defined?(dbh) and dbh.connected?
                dbh.disconnect
        end
        raise
      end

# does not work as dbh is never defined!
```

Is there a way to achieve this so that the error handling block has access to the local variables in whichever controller or method the error occurred?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to create a helper method that'll help you to handle db-connection (moreover, remove duplicate code) rather than let controllers do that.

```rb
def odbc_connect_to(dsn_name, username, password, &block)
  dbh = ODBC.connect(dsn_name, username, password) #(*)
  if dbh&.connected?
    block&.call(dbh)
  else
    raise StandardError.new("Couldn't connect to db #{dsn_name}")
  end
rescue => e
  puts e
  # handling db error
ensure
  dbh.disconnect
end
```

then

```rb
def show
 odbc_connect_to(dsn_name, username, password) do |dbh|
   @author = getAuthor(dbh, params[:id])
   @books= getBooks(dbh, @author)
 end
end
```

Note (*) : it maybe expensive to create/close db connections, which makes it worthwhile to create a connection pool.